# Google Apps Marketplace publication rejected

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I have published my Extension Sheets Add-on but it's rejected !

[image]

Where can I found the details for the reject to correct the problem and re-publish after corrections ?

Comment: As far as I know, once the item was rejected, the owner will receive the details why the item was rejected. Be sure this is not owned by a group account, so that you will be able to receive any feedback from the Engineers.

Comment: For the moment, I didn't receive any emails. And I'm sure that it's not owned by a group account. Is there a way to contact support?

Comment: You can try and fillup this form to log your [issue](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/dev_account_transfer).

Comment: After some days my application is published and available in the Market place but I always have the status "GAM: Rejected". What does that mean?

Comment: It means your latest update on your item has been rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the OAuth consent screen the tab "DOMAIN VERIFICATION" was not completed.
When I completed it and re-submit my addon, it was published successfully.